# Single pass z80 assembler (source or useable on windows)

Tags: assembly, z80

I have recently got my hands on a Z80 system and have been writing a dissasmbler for a debugger (pushing in instructions that are pulled from the memory of the Z80y). I can get the instruction however the problem arises when assembling the ASM, I am finding that most assemblers either don't understand the full set of instructions properly or get some instructions confused meaning it is impossible to convert back to ASM correctly. What I ask from you guys today is if you have one that actually works (the source would be even better). I would also like for it to have a single pass option because it makes this impossible otherwise (well nearly).

One final thing would be to know if anyone has a complete set on instructions for testing as at the moment I only have an 8080 list which means I can't test the extended instructions.

Thanks a lot for any link/files,
  Andy A

Comment: You are trying to use an 8080 assembler. Use Z80 tools for a Z80. http://www.z80.info/z80sdt.htm

Comment: For a complete set of instructions, check out http://clrhome.org/table/. The instructions shown in red are (or perhaps, were) unofficially undocumented.

Comment: sdcc has an open source assembler.

Comment: The last time I used SDCC, its assembler lacked support for macros, which I saw as a major drawback though it might not matter for your purposes. This was a year or two ago, so things might have changed since. WLA-DX has worked well for me and is open source, though it's not single-pass IIRC.

Comment: Actually you could just use Zilog Developer Studio II and just not use any of the new eZ80 instructions. http://store.zilog.com/index.php?option=com_ixxocart&Itemid=1&p=product&id=29&parent=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assembler I use for my Z-80 programming projects is zmac.

I've built my own version for Windows with some extensions:

http://members.shaw.ca/gp2000/zmac.html

A Google search for "z80 zmac" can help you locate the original source code.

It's not a single pass assembler, but I think it will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

The [Z88 development kit](http://www.z88dk.org/forum/) also contains an assembler (z80asm), as well as a C compiler.

It's a two-pass assembler, though. I don't think that a single pass approach would be useful. How would you assemble a JP to a label defined later in a single pass?!

The z88dk toolchain seems to be very portable. I am currently trying to port it to my Zilog eZ80 based platform itself.

Comment: One-pass assemblers are technically straightforward; I used to build these back in the 70s.  A forward reference (load,store,jmp) is handled by emitting a dummy placeholder, recording the placeholder in to-be-resolved-list, and generating a patch with the "fixed up" instruction when the forward referenced information becomes available. In practice the to-be-resolved list never gets very big.   You can even do this with forward references to EQUs and or arbitrary expressions. From a functionality point of view, one-vs-two pass makes little difference, and assembly speed doesn't matter much now.

Comment: Well, when this is your definition of a single pass assembler, then z80asm is one. I thought that the patching of the adresses counts as a second pass.

Comment: "A pass" in assembly is generally interpreted as "reading the assembly source code".  If your assembler only reads that source code once, then it is technically a one-pass assembler; if it reads the source code twice to collect symbols in the first pass and produce code in the second, it is two pass.  One clever assembler produced by a cohort read the source once and tokenized it to a buffer during the first pass, and then reprocessed the tokens in pass two, making it arguably one-pass. It was much faster than a corresponding real two pass assembler.  Would not be practical in a small machine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official up-to-date Z80 manual: http://www.zilog.com/manage_directlink.php?filepath=docs/z80/um0080 .

It includes full description of instruction set architecture.

Comment: Very useful manual that I never managed to find, unfortunately this project has been dead for a while and it doesn't look like I will be picking it up any time soon. Despite that thank you for the documentation for other that may stumble upon this thread.

Comment: But still BEWARE of typos in that doc! :) Particularly, there are still typos in binary codes for ``XOR s`` commands.